# using class name in class body simultaneously

Tags: c#, class, types

I do not know my question title is true or not. Anyway:

Why in the example below, we can use `LinkedListNode` type for our properties? Because the type is created immediately, so we can use it, without instantiate it?

```
public class LinkedListNode
{
    public LinkedListNode(object value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public LinkedListNode Next { get; internal set; }
    public LinkedListNode Prev { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: This should not be a problem. Are you sure it does not work? What is your error message?

Comment: This is not a problem. I want to know how this code works. In fact, the philosophy of this code.

Comment: That is simple. For `Next` and `Prev` you do not create instances of the `LinkedListNode`, just declare them as a reference. If you mean parsing: usually compilers keep track the identifier symbols with their kind so it recognises they mean the same class.

Comment: So, this is not except the concept of instantiating. We define a tag (reference) and tie it to a bag (instance of a class). Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the properties (below)

```
public LinkedListNode Next { get; internal set; }
public LinkedListNode Prev { get; internal set; }
```

don't get created automatically, they will be null until something assigns an instantiated LinkedListNode to them (in this case, because of the internal set , something internal needs to set them)

However the point being is, you can create classes with properties of the same type as your class

you can think of the following situation

```
public class user
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public User BestFriend { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, a `User` can have a `BestFriend` of type `User`, all makes sense

However just because you have a `User` doesn't mean he has a `BestFriend`, and that property will stay `null` until something assigns a `User` to it